# How do I hot-swap a view with deduplicated table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a data pipeline that streams data into daily BigQuery tables (data_20170801, data_20170802, etc.). Due to the standard technicalities of the process, data may contain duplicate rows. If I want to query data from today, I create a query that deduplicates the duplicate rows.

On top of that, I have a daily "cleaning" process that fixes "yesterday" by selecting from the now immutable "dirty" table (containing duplicates), and creating a new deduplicated table.

Now, if one wants to query a time frame that includes "clean" and "dirty" tables, the query becomes a bit cumbersome, due to it including the clean query on the clean tables, and an adapted deduplicating query on the dirty tables.

My question is what's the best way of hiding this business logic from the query? I was thinking of creating a deduplicating view for the dirty table, in the same format (and naming convention) of the clean ones, but then I would like to overwrite it in the cleaning process, without any downtime.

How could this be done?

Comment: at which point you would expect downtime here? i don't see any. you should be ok with your plan

Comment: I haven't seen clear documentation of the behavior of overwriting a view with a table, or overwriting tables in general. Is this a transactional process? Will the view be available until the overwriting is complete? I've also haven't been able to find a table rename api, which could have been useful in similar cases.